# JsonConverter Serialize failing - returning a string rather than json object

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-web-api, serialization

I am not sure what has happened, but all of a sudden I am getting weird behaviour in my controller.

The controller is set up to return a json serialized object like so:

```
return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented));
```

It was working correctly but now it is returning this instead:

```
"{\r\n  \"ProductID\": 1,\r\n  \"ArticleID\": \"a1\",\r\n  \"ProductDescription\": \"new dress\",\r\n  \"ProductType\": \"1\",\r\n  \"MaterialDescription\": \"cotton\",\r\n  \"Qty\": 1,\r\n  \"SizeID\": 1,\r\n  \"RetailPrice\": 22.00,\r\n  \"ImagePath\": \"C:\\\\Users\\\\Harry\\\\Desktop\\\\IMG_8931.JPG\",\r\n  \"ProductVaritiesID\": 1,\r\n  \"Discount\": 0.00,\r\n  \"QuantityInStock\": 10,\r\n  \"ProductTypeID\": 1,\r\n  \"ProductOrderQuantity\": 0\r\n}"
```

However, if I return this object without serializing like so:

```
        return Ok(result);
```

It returns the an object like so:

```
{
    "ProductID": 1,
    "ArticleID": "a1",
    "ProductDescription": "new dress",
    "ProductType": "1",
    "MaterialDescription": "cotton",
    "Qty": 1,
    "SizeID": 1,
    "RetailPrice": 22,
    "ImagePath": "C:\\Users\\Harry\\Desktop\\IMG_8931.JPG",
    "ProductVaritiesID": 1,
    "Discount": 0,
    "QuantityInStock": 10,
    "ProductTypeID": 1,
    "ProductOrderQuantity": 0
}

Controller:
        [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "GET")]
        [Route("api/product/getproductbybarcode")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(Product))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetProductByBarcode(string barcodevalue)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(barcodevalue))
                return NotFound(); //replace with correct message

            var result = _iproduct.GetProductByBarcode(barcodevalue);

            return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented));
        }
```

I cannot figure out, what is causing the Json serialization to fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you moved your method from MVC to MVC Web Api, because by default an Api serializes the object, that is the idea and you don't have to call the serializer as you do in a MVC application (not Api)

So this

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("Api/Values/GetByID")]
        [ActionName("GetByID")]
        public dynamic GetByID(int id)
        {
            return new {name = "Joe", value = "team" };
        }
```

Retutns

```
{
    "name": "Joe",
    "value": "team"
}
```

And this

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("Api/Values/GetByID")]
        [ActionName("GetByID")]
        public dynamic GetByID(int id)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { name = "Joe", value = "team" }, Formatting.Indented);
        }
```

Returns

```
"{\r\n  \"name\": \"Joe\",\r\n  \"value\": \"team\"\r\n}"
```

This is because it is somehow serializing two times

Comment: Thanks for the input, no I have not moved it from an MVC app to a web api. I just find it strange, it was serializing correctly, although you are right i do not need to serialize in web api which I discovered in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
string jsonFormatted = JValue.Parse(json).ToString(Formatting.Indented);
```

Check below link for more details 
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Mar/31/Prettifying-a-JSON-String-in-NET

Also make sure that `content-type:application/json`

Answer (score 0):

JsonConvert.SerializeObject gives you a string as a return type.So if you return the response after serialization then you'll get string response, If you return object then you'll get json object as response.